# Global Error Handling in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, typescript, error-handling

I work with AngularJS and typescript.I also call Rest services to retrieve data from backend.My question is what is the best approach to handle calls error globally for all controller.Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle error globally is it overwrite

> '$exceptionHandler'

Here is  document link
"https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler"

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app');

    // Configure by setting an optional string value for appErrorPrefix.
    // Accessible via config.appErrorPrefix (via config value).

    app.config(['$provide', function ($provide: ng.auto.IProvideService) {
        $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler',
            ['$delegate', 'config', 'logger', extendExceptionHandler]);
    }]);

    // Extend the $exceptionHandler service to also display a toast.
    function extendExceptionHandler($delegate: ng.IExceptionHandlerService, config: config, logger: logger) {
        var appErrorPrefix = config.appErrorPrefix;
        var logError = logger.getLogFn('app', 'error');
        return function (exception: Error, cause: string) {
            $delegate(exception, cause);
            if (appErrorPrefix && exception.message.indexOf(appErrorPrefix) === 0) { return; }

            var errorData = { exception: exception, cause: cause };
            var msg = appErrorPrefix + exception.message;
            logError(msg, errorData, true);
        };
    }
})();
```

https://github.com/johnnyreilly/HotTowel-Angular-TypeScript/blob/master/app/config.exceptionHandler.ts